# Decomposition and reconstruction step in Tabu search

Tags: tabu-search

I'm looking for the step by step to coding the decomposition and reconstruction step in Tabu search heuristic in Java but I don't understand the bolded words.

What is this and how can I explain it in java coding

> After partitioning initial solution to subsets of routes or
>   subproblem. Each subset of route is processed by Tabu Search. The best
>   routes found for every subproblem are simply merged together to form
>   the next solution for decomposition and reconstruction step. After a
>   loop of D&R the final route will be recorded.
>
> The decomposition is based on the **polar angle associated with the
>   center of gravity of each route**. **Using these polar angles**, the
>   domain is partitioned into sectors that approximately contain the same
>   number of routes. Note that the decomposition changes from one D&R to
>   the next by choosing a different starting angle for creating sectors,
>   thus allowing the CROSS exchange heuristic to exploit new pairs of
>   routes.

Thank in advance